# Can .equalsTo() method in Java handle null value?

Tags: java, methods

```
if(dbRecord.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID().getTypeDetailID().equalsTo(applicationPropertyDetailBean.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID()) !=0){
                    isRequiredRoiCall=true;
                }
```

This piece of code returns Null exception when one of the values is null.

Comment: debug your code and findout where null pass. and your condition is `if(string != 0)` change it to `if(String != '0')`

Answer (score 1):

You can add if statement with null checking.

Smth like this:

```
if(dbRecord.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID() != null && ...)
```

Or use `Optional.ofNullable`

Answer (score 0):

You shoud make sure:

dbRecord != null

dbRecord.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID() != null

dbRecord.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID().getTypeDetailID() != null

applicationPropertyDetailBean != null

Comment: this means that .equalsTo method is not capable of handling null values, right?

Comment: @user15778476 no! that means you can't call a function from a "null", if dbRecord is null,  it will be null.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID(), if dbRecord.getPropertyDocumentTypeDetailID() is null, it will be null.getTypeDetailID()!